# SQL date difference ignoring years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two date columns and I would like to calculate their differences in Months/Days and exclude years.

Assuming the first date is 10/30/2017, comparing it to the current date, its difference should one. If the current date is 10/30/2018, the difference should also be one.

A few examples:

```
Schedule Date:10/30/2017   Current Date 10/29/2017  Diff  1
Schedule Date:10/30/2017   Current Date 11/30/2017  Diff 30
Schedule Date:10/30/2017   Current Date 10/29/2018  Diff 1
Schedule Date:10/30/2017   Current Date 11/30/2018  Diff 30
Schedule Date:10/30/2017   Current Date 10/29/2019  Diff 1
Schedule Date:10/30/2017   Current Date 11/30/2019  Diff 30
```

Comment: Can you show your code for getting the difference in months and days?  It is not obvious how you are doing that.  Why is 2017-11-30 given as "30" instead of "1 month"?

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: You can ignore leap years.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 SELECT ABS(365 * DATEDIFF(year, '10/30/2017', '11/30/2018')
 -  DATEDIFF(day, '10/30/2017', '11/30/2018')) AS DateDiff;
```

Note that the difference between `10/30/` and `11/30/` can't be 30 days as you have shown.It is 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Common Table Expression to get your results like below :

```
DECLARE @Schedule_Date datetime = '10/30/2017'
DECLARE @Current_Date datetime = '11/30/2019'

;WITH usingCTE AS 
(
    SELECT CAST(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar, @Schedule_Date, 102), 1, 4, CAST(YEAR(@Current_Date) AS varchar)) AS datetime) AS Schedule_Date 
)
SELECT abs(DATEDIFF(day, @Current_Date, Schedule_Date)) FROM usingCTE
```

Another approach of the query :

```
DECLARE @Schedule_Date datetime = '10/30/2017'
DECLARE @Current_Date datetime = '11/30/2017'

SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(day, 
           REPLACE(@Schedule_Date, DATEPART(year, @Schedule_Date), 
           DATEPART(year, @Current_Date)), -- replace the year with current year
           @Current_Date))
```

Comment: You don't have to post multiple answers, include all your solutions in one.

Comment: @MieSan - Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, first adjust the date to be in the same year, then calculate the number of days different between the two dates:

```
DECLARE @ScheduleDate DATE = '2017-10-30';
DECLARE @Dates TABLE (CurrentDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES ('2017-10-29'),('2017-11-30'),('2018-10-29'),('2018-11-30'),('2019-10-29'),('2019-11-30');
SELECT @ScheduleDate ScheduleDate, *
FROM @Dates a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT AdjustedDate=DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(@ScheduleDate) - YEAR(a.CurrentDate), a.CurrentDate)) b
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Diff=ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @ScheduleDate, b.AdjustedDate))) c
```