# SQL Query That Returns Rows when a date does not fall exactly on an anniversary which could be a number of years in the future

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables we'll call them `TableA` and `TableB`.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DateOne Date Not NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE TableB 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TableAId int NOT NULL,
    DateTwo Date Not NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (TableAId) References TableA(Id)
);
```

I insert the following data.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (DateOne)
VALUES ('2020-01-02');

INSERT INTO TableB (TableAId, DateTwo)
VALUES (1,'2021-01-01'),
       (1,'2022-02-02'),
       (1,'2023-01-01');
```

I want to write a query that returns all of the Id's of `B` where the date is exactly one or more calendar year minus one day from A's date one.

Pseudo code:

```
SELECT A.Id, b.Id,  
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON b.AId = A.Id
WHERE (B.DateTwo is anniversary of A.DateOne minus one day.)
```

The query ran against this data should return the first and last values from the B table as they are equal to exactly one year (minus a day). The middle value should not appear as it is not equal to a an anniversary minus one day.

Comment: Consumable sample data, and expected results, would really help us help you here, rather than a very abstract description.

Comment: Please note tables have columns, not fields.

Comment: i use columns when i talk about postgres and fields/cols interchangeably when mssql.  anyway, look at DATEDIFF - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @ThomA i've made some updates to this to actually give some tables and example data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL date difference ignoring years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002224/sql-date-difference-ignoring-years)

Comment: `WHERE DATEPART(month, b.DateTwo) = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(day, -1, a.DateOne)) AND DATEPART(day, b.DateTwo) = DATEPART(day, DATEADD(day, -1, a.DateOne))` maybe?

Comment: You have conflicting descriptions. You say "in the future", but the first row is not "in the future".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier in a [standards-compliant database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/features.html), and Transact SQL is not a standards-compliant database. The following suggestion smells approximately like that of @Charlieface with a sign change and [runs in TSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ujk9E6NJ):

```sql
create table TableA (
    ID int primary key,
    DateOne date not null
);

create table TableB (
    ID int primary key,
    TableAID int not null references TableA(ID),
    DateTwo date not null
);

insert into TableA(ID, DateOne) values
(1, '2021-01-02');

insert into TableB(ID, TableAId, DateTwo) values
(1, 1, '2021-01-01'),
(2, 1, '2022-02-02'),
(3, 1, '2023-01-01');

select TableA.ID as TableAID,
       TableB.ID as TableBID
from TableA
left join TableB on (
  TableB.TableAID = TableA.ID
  and datepart(month, DateOne) = datepart(month, dateadd(day, 1, DateTwo))
  and datepart(day,   DateOne) = datepart(day,   dateadd(day, 1, DateTwo))
);
```